# Unwanted blank line in python output

Tags: python

For class I am supposed to write a code that output asterisk in the form of a number 8. I don't understand what is wrong with my code and it adds a new line at the start, but in this challenge.

So, the expected output is supposed to look like this:

```
*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****
```

While my code looks like this:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print()
    for j in range(0,5):
        if i%2==0:
            print("*",end='')        
        else:
            if j==0 or j==4:                
                print("*",end='')
            else:
                print(" ",end='')
```

but my output adds a new line at the start( so it looks like the expected output with an extra new line) then prints the rest of the code as intended.

please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You're printing an extra line at the beginning, because of the `print()` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Remove `print()` at the top and that's all.

Comment: @AksenP If they only do that, they won't get *any* newlines, everything will be on the same line.

Comment: You need to move that `print()` to the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar, that's why the OP should understand how to deal with it, cause the purpose of studying is studying)

Comment: @Barmar I moved the print() to the bottom of the loop but it got rid of all my new lines

Comment: I suspect you indented it wrong, it works here: https://ideone.com/woOkjX

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### You are starting with a blank line, and shouldn't

You could change this line:

```
print()
```

to:

```
if i>0:
    print()
```

So that the code, with correct indenting, becomes:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    if i>0:
        print()
    for j in range(0,5):
        if i%2==0:
            print("*",end='')        
        elif j==0 or j==4:                
            print("*",end='')
        else:
            print(" ",end='')
```

Alternatively, you could move the printing of `()` to the end of the `for i` loop, so that it would no longer need to be in an `if`. That is a little more conventional, since it finishes the output with a newline.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,5):
        if i%2==0:
            print("*",end='')        
        elif j==0 or j==4:                
            print("*",end='')
        else:
            print(" ",end='')
    print() # <----- No `if`, if you place this `print()` here instead.
```

Comment: line 3 or line 4. I changed line 4 and it got rid of the 3 asterisks between 1st and 5th asterisk and added them to the blank spaces on the other lines.

Comment: Sorry that was the line numbering based on your pasted image. You have now pasted in the code as text, which is great, but the indentation is lost. I have now removed references to line numbers and replaced with quotations of the line.

Comment: Thanks for the help I combined both of your solutions and got rid of the indentation on the bottom print and that turned out to be the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` call should be at the bottom of the loop, not the top, so you don't print a blank line at the beginning.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,5):
        if i%2==0:
            print("*",end='')        
        else:
            if j==0 or j==4:                
                print("*",end='')
            else:
                print(" ",end='')
    print()
```

You can also do it without the nested loop, since there are just two strings to print, they don't need to be created dynamically.

```
for i in range(5):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("*****")
    else:
        print("*   *")
```